# How to upgrade lighttpd on Windows 10 using Cygwin/Mingw

Tags: linux, windows, webserver, cygwin, mingw

There is this project I took from a client who my friend who owes Gym.
They have a POS security scan every month because they use the credit card machine.

if they don't pass the security scan, they get charge until next month. In order for the owner to pass the security check is to have current web service running in the background.

I have to install Lighttpd web server on his Windows 10 as a localhost service running in the background a year ago. It passed the security scan. Now, the program [lighttpd] (http://lighttpd.dtech.hu/) is outdated.

The current version is 1.4.55 [Light](https://www.lighttpd.net/download/) but the only available file is .tar.

I tried looking up on Google how to upgrade lighttpd on windows 10 or install the latest version of lighttpd from scratch LightTPD but I came up short.

I need some guidance on how to proceed. Currently, I am using Windows 10 on VMWare Workstation virtual machine on Ubunut OS laptop

***UPDATE***

I found some articles how to setup lighttpd web services on Google:

http://www.gizmoplex.com/wordpress/gitweb-with-lighttpd-in-cygwin/

http://devtidbits.com/2011/07/01/cygwin-walkthrough-and-beginners-guide-is-it-linux-for-windows-or-a-posix-compatible-alternative-to-powershell/

But they are outdated by several years ago.

***UPDATE #2***

I installed Ubuntu WSL on the windows 10 machine for testing but the localhost only runs if ubuntu program window is open. if its close, the service will stop.

I am looking for Standalone program or maybe have Cygwin running in the background for LightTPD

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this.

```
run.exe bash.exe -c "lighttpd ; bash"
```

taken from this thread.
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/612